# Can I file and I-130 if my passport is expired?

Tags: usa

I am completing the file paperwork for my husband and daugther, but my passport is expired. I went to the embassy and paid the renewal fee, but it will take a month to receive the new passport. Do you think I can proceed with the I-130 filing with my passport expired?.

I have no words to Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Are you a US citizen or a permanent resident? If permanent resident, do you have the card. If so, you only need to provide that to prove that you're a permanent resident. See #4 under General Requirements of the [instructions](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/i-130instr.pdf).

Comment: Thank you mkennedy, I`m a US citizen, my passport expired, what I want to know is can I proceed with the I-130 or do I have to wait for the new passport!. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, a valid passport is not mandatory. You just need to provide one of the many forms of proof of US citizenship:

- US birth certificate showing birth in the US (if born in the US)
- Certificate of Naturalization, Certificate of Citizenship, or Consular Report of Birth Abroad (if born outside the US)
- valid unexpired US passport

If you don't have a valid unexpired US passport, you can use one of the other forms of proof of citizenship that is applicable to you. In another question you said you were born in the US, so you can just provide a copy of your birth certificate.